# Write by C# and Read by python on one file in the same time

Tags: python, c#, store

I have two program one in c# that write to store file and python program that read from the same file
this program must run together, how can I do it? And what the type of file I used to store?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FranzGleichmann what kind of additional information you think is needed? Writing and reading at the same time from same/different processes is perfectly valid operation and I don't see what other info is needed. Obviously question falls into "no research shown" category, but claiming that it is not on-topic is not correct to my understanding.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the "additional information needed" for a good question is: what has been tried/researched so far, and what exactly the _problem_ is. plus: what OP wants to _achieve_ by this - i'd bet there's a better solution than simultaneously accessing a file. as for the link to what's on topic - IMHO it _should_ be required reading for anyone who apparently hasn't read _any_ of SO's help pages yet.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a mutual exclusion problem.

You can create every type of file you want but you should ensure that the writings happen in a correct way.

In order to synchronize the processes you can use a shared semaphore between the python process and c# process, also a shared memory or system event should be fine.

If you are on a unix system you can check [this for python](https://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/)

[this for c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.threading?view=net-6.0)